# Slow response of a Php+MySql application

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx

I am running a chatroom ([phpfreechat](http://www.phpfreechat.net/)) with mysql+php. I have a dedicated server to run this script as it can consume lots of resources. It works all fine with 100 concurrent users. However, recently a user threaten us to kill this chatroom and he is successfully doing this :(

There are only 40 users and chatroom is dead. It takes 10-20 seconds to deliver one message. MySql is eating 300% plus CPU. However, with 100 users (when it's not under attack), chatroom only uses 200-300% CPU. I checked following things to make sure he is not DoSing/DDoSing our server.

```
1 - Limited 3 requests per seconds.
2 - Analyzed access.log to see any weird activity or CRLF slow attacks. There is none.
3 - Looked per IP connections using netstat command and none has lots of connections. 
4 - I disabled ping of death
```

Static website on the server works all fine even under attack. I am assuming he is exploiting mysql via chatroom by sending many requests. I ran the following query to see current connections to mysql:

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected'
```

The result is only 7 that looks pretty normal. Is there any other step that I can perform to block his attack and protect my server (chatroom)?

Comment: You can enable mysql log to see which and how many statements are being called. The slow query log also gives the troubled ones.

Comment: check nginx and apache logs enable ddos blocker

Comment: @Tim3880, MySql logs are already enabled and there is nothing weird. Is there anything specific I should log or look for in the logs?

Comment: @FerozAkbar, I am only running nginx. I looked for the logs already as I mentioned in the question. Access logs do not show any bumps in user requests or many requests from the same IP.

Comment: they do log every request you have to filter the logs as per your requirement

Comment: @FerozAkbar, I already checked nginx logs using Weblog Expert lite. There is no issue with nginx IMHO. ASAP, I restart mysql everything works fine till attacker start the attack again.

Comment: keep checking `show processlist;` which will show quries that are runnning at that time, & in apache logs check to which page there are lot of requests and it'll also log the ip so you can block it

Comment: If there is nothing abnormal in your access log, then I guess some queries are running too slow (like the one takes 20 seconds to deliver a message). Run the query in your mysql admin to find out the reason.

Comment: @FerozAkbar, thanks about show processlist; command. It shows me there are two queries that takes 100+ time and info column it show NULL and command column has sleep value. What does it mean? These two queries are always present in processlist; All other queries time is 0.

Answer (score 1):

(from the last comment)
ahh, that means the attacker is trying some queries using mysql injection, so first you have to

**1) Sanitize your inputs**

If you are using pdo or mysqli then use bind params (prepared statements) feature to filter your inputs

or at least `mysqliescapestring` the inputs

and if your php page takes a value something like this `.../page.php?id=10` then check the value & make sure it is integer only like below

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])){ //do operations...}else { //suspicious input given by someone so exit}
```

**2) limit query execution time**

As you are having long running queries (which are by hacker), then limit the query execution time , use statement timeouts, wait_timeout features so that query will have limited execution time

And as I said earlier in your apache access log you'll find these sleep queries as GET parameters so, find it and block that ip